# index 33 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 33

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error at this line

```
my_predictions = prediction_matrix[:,current_user_id-1]+Ymean.flatten()
```

This is the code. Please tell me how do I fix it?

```
def recommend(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")
    if not request.user.is_active:
        raise Http404
    df=pd.DataFrame(list(Myrating.objects.all().values()))
    nu=df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
    current_user_id= request.user.id
    # if new user not rated any movie
    if current_user_id>nu:
        movie=Movie.objects.get(id=15)
        q=Myrating(user=request.user,movie=movie,rating=0)
        q.save()

    print("Current user id: ",current_user_id)
    prediction_matrix,Ymean = Myrecommend()
    my_predictions = prediction_matrix[:,current_user_id-1]+Ymean.flatten()
    pred_idxs_sorted = np.argsort(my_predictions)
    pred_idxs_sorted[:] = pred_idxs_sorted[::-1]
    pred_idxs_sorted=pred_idxs_sorted+1
    print(pred_idxs_sorted)
    preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pred_idxs_sorted)])
    movie_list=list(Movie.objects.filter(id__in = pred_idxs_sorted,).order_by(preserved)[:10])
    return render(request,'web/recommend.html',{'movie_list':movie_list})
```

Comment: Indexing usually starts from 0. It could be the case that the columns are available at indices 0 through 32 (33-1, because indexing starts at 0 instead of 1). Is this the issue ?

Comment: You have provided a lot of code and No data. Your [mre] should include an example of the data and you should only include the code necessary to reproduce the problem - you may need to make a *toy* example. When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: I see you are printing `current_user_id` is it what you expected? If not you need to figure out why.  Do the user ID's start at `one`??  Are the user ID's *contiguous*? - i.e. is user ID 12 the twelfth user in the *sequence*  or are there missing user IDs so that user ID 12 is only the seventh in the sequence?